# How can I update on click function depending on what class a div currently has?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want different things to happen to my div when clicked, depending on which class it currently has. I am changing the class of my div using jQuery. But, the first on click. [Here](https://codepen.io/flinch85/pen/OJyqYvm)'s a simple example.

When the `div`'s class changes, clicking it should now make it blue, but it still goes red according to the original classes function.

```js
$('.class-1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});

$('.class-2').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});

$('.change-class').on('click', function() {
  $('.class-1').prop('class', 'class-2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="class-1">button</button>
<button class="change-class">change button class</button>
```

Can I make the function switch dynamically when the class changes?

Comment: Using `$('.some-class').on('click', ...)` will apply a click listener to every `.some-class` element only at that moment in time - it doesn't create a global rule that all `.some-class` elements that will ever exist get that click listener

Comment: It can be done. You may or may not get there unaided. You're going to have to maintain state. Now, you can do it with a variable in the code or **to avoid duplicating information** you may simply check the state of the element (e.g check for the presence/absence of a class) and perform an action based upon the current state.

Comment: https://codepen.io/flinch85/pen/OJyqYvm?editors=1010 i edited a bit you might wanna check like this =) Oh it's not the best way tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the `click()` event for elements with the class `class-2` using event delegation with [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```js
$('.class-1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});

$(document).on('click', '.class-2', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});

$('.change-class').on('click', function() {
  $('.class-1').prop('class', 'class-2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="class-1">button</button>
<button class="change-class">change button class</button>
```

Comment: @flinch85 Glad that I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You save the color as temporary variable

```
var myColor = 'red';
$('.class-1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', myColor );
  myColor = myColor ==='blue' ? 'red':'blue';
});
```